# Flexbox Button: Works in Chrome and Edge, broken in FF

Tags: css, html, firefox, flexbox

I've a Button which uses Flexbox inside for Layout. This works perfectly in Chrome and Edge.

[image]

In Firefox it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Ignore the Language change in the Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In some broswers rather than using things like: `display: flex;` you need to use: `display: -webkit-flex;`

There are other workarounds which you can get from Google but I use css-tricks for specific areas I am unsure on.

I had this exact issue some time ago, webkit extensions will work fine. You can add it above, below `display: flex;` and it won't conflict.

UPDATED: For firefox try adding: `display: -moz-box;`